# React MUI - Clearing input on Autocomplete component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an Autocomplete component which displays the coutries name and flags as in the example from the MUI doc.

[image: Edit CountrySelect Material Demo (forked)]

My goal is simply the following: once the Autocomplete component is clicked, the country's name must be cleared displaying only the placeholder.

I achieved this with a simple **onClick** event in the renderInput which triggers the following function:

```
  const handleClear = (e) => {
    e.target.value = "";
  };
```

If trying the code everything works as expected, *apparently*.
Actually, the clearing happens **only** when the country's name is clicked, but if a different portion of the component is clicked, like the *flag* or the *dropdown arrow*, **the country's name is simply focused, not cleared**.

In short, here the **current** behaviour:

[image: current behaviour]

and here the **expected** behaviour:
[image: expected]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's behavior occurs because when you click on the flag, the `e.target` won´t be the `input` element, but the wrapper `div`. You can see this just adding a `console.log` to the `handleClear` function:

```js
const handleClear = (e) => {
    console.log("clicked TARGET ELEMENT: ", e.target);

    // If you click on the input, will see:
    // <input ...

    // And if you click on the flag, you will see:
    // <div ...
};
```

If you want to control the input state value and the text value separately, you probably should go with the two states control - check it on MUI [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#controlled-states).

The code will be something like:

```js
export default function CountrySelect() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  const handleClear = (e) => {
    console.log("clicked TARGET ELEMENT: ", e.target);
    setInputValue("");
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="country-select-demo"
      disableClearable
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
        setInputValue(newInputValue);
      }}
      openOnFocus
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      options={countries}
      autoHighlight
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <Box
          component="li"
          sx={{ "& > img": { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }}
          {...props}
        >
          <img
            loading="lazy"
            width="20"
            src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
            srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
            alt=""
          />
          {option.label} ({option.code}) +{option.phone}
        </Box>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Choose a country"
          placeholder="Choose a country"
          onClick={handleClear}
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            startAdornment: value ? (
              <InputAdornment disablePointerEvents position="start">
                <img
                  loading="lazy"
                  width="48"
                  src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${value.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
                  srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${value.code.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
                  alt=""
                />
              </InputAdornment>
            ) : null
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Great, it works! It is also the correct approach because there is the separation between the value and the text value.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onClick` on TextField, you can use **`onOpen`** props and pass `handleClear` function in it. It works then. Selected value gets cleared whenever autocomplete is open.

Working Demo: [CodeSandBox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/countryselect-material-demo-forked-d6bply?file=/demo.js)